# How to implement selection sort with a comparator in Java

Tags: java

I am developing a program to perform selection sort on a list of strings. The input for the program is 6 strings. The output for the program should be the list of strings sorted by their last character.

Here is what I have tried

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Exercise_20_21 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 6 strings: ");
        // Step 1: proccess strings from input
        String data = input.next();
        String[] list = data.split(" ");
        for(int i=0; i < list.length; i++){
            System.out.print(list[i]+" ");
        }
        selectionSort(list, new Comparator<String>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(String w1, String w2){
                if(w1.charAt(0) > w2.charAt(0)){
                    return -1;
                }
                else if( w1.charAt(0) < w2.charAt(0)){
                    return 1;
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
        for(int i=0; i < list.length; i++){
            System.out.print(list[i]+" ");
        }
    }

    

    public static <E> void selectionSort(E[] list, Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        Arrays.sort(list,comparator);
    }
}
```

Expected:

```
Enter 5 strings: red blue green yellow orange pink
red blue orange pink green yellow
```

Actual:

```
Enter 6 strings: red blue green yellow orange pink
red red
```

How can I start on debugging this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is not with the comparator itself. You would want to use [`input.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) for being able to read an entire line. Using [`next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) will read only until the next delimiter (which is space in your case).

For the comparator part, Java already provides a comparator for comparing strings and other objects. This is [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) and can be used as such:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 6 strings: ");
    // Step 1: proccess strings from input
    String data = input.nextLine();
    String[] list = data.split(" ");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));

    selectionSort(list, Comparator.naturalOrder());

    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
}


public static <E> void selectionSort(E[] list, Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    Arrays.sort(list, comparator);
}
```